# How to delete a file using absolute path in andriod

Tags: android, file, absolute-path

How can i delete a file in android using the abosolute file path i have added the provider_paths as some suggested but the file shows delete in my toast function but the file is not deleted, i have use the provided_path.xml file to share the files in the same program which works fine but i can't get it to work here in the delete function here is the code am using

```
            File photoLcl = new File(String.valueOf(arrayList.get(i).getAbsoluteFile()));
            try {
                Uri imageUriLcl = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity,
                        activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +
                                ".provider", photoLcl);
                ContentResolver contentResolver = activity.getContentResolver();
                contentResolver.delete(imageUriLcl, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(activity, "File Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(activity, " Error "+e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: new File(abspath).delete();

Comment: You are showing a toast without checking the return value of delete().

Comment: still not working even after using                                                                         `File photoLcl = new File(arrayList.get(i).getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: Do you really think that we know what you have in your array list? Tell the used absolute path!

Comment: When i used a string to get the absolute path i got something like this **/storage/emulated/0/Documents/file-test.pdf**

Comment: And you are trying this on an Andtoid 10 device? And why didnt you post your new code? I dont see you using File:delete().